# How does the `indexOf` method on a string work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, indexof

The example below gets the last character of a string and calls `indexOf` on the character.

```javascript
var sentence = "welcome to bootcamp prep";
var lastChar = sentence[sentence.length - 1];
console.log(lastChar); // "p"
console.log(sentence.indexOf(lastChar)); // 18
```

I understand that `lastChar` contains the last character in the string, and that `indexOf` returns a character that you are searching for.

Why does the call return 18? How does `indexOf` work?

Comment: `indexOf` returns the position of the character, not the character itself. In this question, the last character is at the position 18.

Comment: Simply read the documentation: [`indexOf`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Comment: @Jacob  The last character is not at position 18,.. :) it's at position 23..  This is because the code shown finds the first character position of the last character.

Comment: @Keith sorry, I read the question very quickly before downvoting and explaining the function of indexOf. My bad. Still not a great question though :(

Answer (score 1):

The [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function of a string does not return a character but rather returns the position of the first place that string or character is found, not the character itself.

In this question, the last character is `"p"`, as found by this line:

```javascript
var lastChar = sentence[sentence.length - 1];
```

However when looking at the string, you can see that the letter `"p"` is found more than once:

```javascript
"welcome to bootcamp prep"
//                 ^ ^  ^
//                18 20 23
```

The numbers indicated in the comment (18, 20, and 23) represent the indexes (locations) of the character within the string.

What do these indexes mean? In JavaScript, indexes start at 0, so the first letter ("w") will be at index 0. In this string, the character `"p"` is found at places 19, 21, and 24, which translate to the indexes 18, 20, and 23.

The first instance of the searched string `"p"` is at index 18. Therefore, when running this line:

```javascript
console.log(sentence.indexOf(lastChar)); // 18
```

The result will be 18, the index of the first instance of the last character.

(Side note: assuming you are a beginner when it comes to JavaScript - try not to use the `var` keyword whenever possible. If the variable needs to change, use `let`, or if the variable stays the same, use `const`.)

Answer (score 0):

Because indexOf returns the first letter that is found matching the argument.

`welcome to bootcam[p] <-- here prep` is found.

JavaScript uses primitive data types so you string is just a string and holds no reference to the original value.

Answer (score 0):

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

The [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) doesn't return the character, it return the position of the character which will be 18.